# WordPress Events Calendar PHP not working on Godaddy server, but works in WAMP localhost

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

This code works on my WAMP localhost, but not on the Godaddy server, I checked the php versions and they are the same, been having a tough time trying to figure out what the issue is. Any one have suggestions? Thank You

website: http://www.thearcticplayhouse.com

```
    <div id="index-row3" class="widthfull clearfix">

        <img src="<?php print IMAGES; ?>/upcoming_events.png" title="Arctic playhouse shows" class="alignleft upcoming"/>

        <div class="wrapper-events width100 alignleft">
                    <?php

                            global $post;

                            // Retrieve the next 5 upcoming events
                            $date = new DateTime();
                            $events = tribe_get_events( array(

                                   'posts_per_page' => 5,
                                   'start_date' => strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d'))
                            ) );

                    foreach ( $events as $post ) { 

                                setup_postdata( $post );
                                $tribeDate = tribe_get_start_date();
                                $displayDate = explode(" ", $tribeDate);

                    ?>
            <article id="event-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                <div id="event-post"  class="alignleft">

                        <div class="alignleft">

                              <ul class="event-date">

                                  <li class="month"><?php echo substr($displayDate[0], 0, 3); ?></li>
                                  <li class="day"><?php echo $displayDate[1]; ?></li>
                                  <li class="event-time"><?php echo $displayDate[2]; ?> <?php echo $displayDate[3]; ?></li>

                              </ul>                  

                        </div>                      


                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>  

                         <div id="event-content">

                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"  class="alignleft"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-events-image'); ?></a>


                                <div class="alignleft info">

                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

                                </div>

                                <div class="alignleft price">

                                    <p>Price: <?php echo "$" . tribe_get_cost(); ?></p>

                                </div>



                        </div>                      

                </div>

            </article>      
                    <?php

                    }


                    ?>

                    <?php   

                            if($events == null) {

                    ?>

            <article> 

                <div id="event-post-none"  class="alignleft">
                        <div class="aligncenter">

                            <p>There are no upcoming events. Please check back soon.</p>

                        </div>
                </div>                                          

            </article> 

                    <?php } ?>

        </div>

        <img src="<?php print IMAGES; ?>/upcoming_events-btm.png" title="Arctic playhouse shows"  class="alignleft upcoming" />

</div>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by changing

```
'start_date' => strtotime($date->format('Y-m-d'))
```

to

```
'start_date' => strtotime(current_time('Y-m-d'))
```

Comment: Ok, removed strtotime() and it seems to be working now. Cross my fingers.

Answer (score 0):

Seralized data? I've had so many problems migrating installations until I found this handy tool.

[Serialized Data Replacement](http://pixelentity.com/wordpress-search-replace-domain/)

> If you have created your test site with a different URL then the finishing live site which is more than likely, (unless you are using Virtual Hosts and are swapping between local and remote IP addresses) you may run into issues with some data not being migrated to the live site.
>
> This data may include WordPress widgets not showing, certain plugins or theme data is missing. The reason this data may not have made the migration trip is because it is lost as the data has been serialized in the database with the old URL and then can’t be unserialized as there is a new URL.

The best I can explain is that every URL has a serialized character count in the SQL database - that changes upon migrating to different server, usually. It breaks $hit.

Comment: I exported my sql db, then used that tool you sent me, renamed my old database, and exported the downloaded file into the new database, but it is still happening.